# Having problems rending 3d models on aruco markers using tvec/rvec

Tags: opencv, graphics, augmented-reality, aruco, rajawali

My graduation project team and I are working on marker-based AR application where in one of the tasks we want to draw some 3d models on markers, we are using opencv to detect markers, and rajawali for drawing the 3d models.

The problem is the tvec/rvec we get from `Aruco.estimatePoseSingleMarkers(...)` doesn't map correctly to location and rotation on the markers, although we can draw the axis accurately.

[image of the 3d model on the marker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7c25E.jpg)

So we wanted to ask:

1. Is there a processing needed on the tvec/rvec needed before using them to get the position and rotation?
2. Is there some alternatives for marker-detection that are more convenient to use than opencv with rajawali?
3. What could be the cause for them to be inaccurate?

Code:

1. marker-detection

```java
public void markerDetection(Mat frame)
{
    ids = new Mat();
    corners = new ArrayList<>();
    Aruco.detectMarkers(frame, markerDictionary, corners, ids);

    List<MarkerData> newDetectedMarkers = new ArrayList<>();

    if(ids.size().height > 0)
    {
        rvecs = new Mat();
        tvecs = new Mat();
        Aruco.estimatePoseSingleMarkers(corners, markerLength, cameraMatrix, distortionCoef, rvecs, tvecs);

        for(int i=0; i<ids.size().height; i++)
        {
            double[] rvecArray = rvecs.get(i, 0), tvecArray = tvecs.get(i, 0);
            Mat rvec = new Mat(3, 1, CvType.CV_64FC1), tvec = new Mat(3, 1, CvType.CV_64FC1);
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
                rvec.put(j, 0, rvecArray[j]);
                tvec.put(j, 0, tvecArray[j]);
            }

            multiply(rvec, new Scalar(180.0 / Math.PI), rvec); // transform them to degree

            MarkerData newMarker = new MarkerData(rvec, tvec, corners.get(i), (int)ids.get(i, 0)[0]);
            newDetectedMarkers.add(newMarker);
        }
    }

    updateDetectedMarkers(newDetectedMarkers); // update the detected markers
}
```

2. Rendering

```java
@Override
protected void onRender(long elapsedRealtime, double deltaTime) {
    super.onRender(elapsedRealtime, deltaTime);
    getCurrentScene().clearChildren();
    List<MarkerData> markerData = markerDetector.getDetectedMarkers();
    for (MarkerData marker : markerData) {
        try {
            int id = R.raw.monkey;
            LoaderOBJ parser = new LoaderOBJ(mContext.getResources(), mTextureManager, id);
            parser.parse();

            Object3D object = parser.getParsedObject();
            object.setMaterial(defaultMaterial);
            object.setScale(0.3);

            Mat rvec = marker.getRvec(); // 3x1 Mat
            Mat tvec = marker.getTvec(); // 3x1 Mat

            object.setRotation(new Vector3(rvec.get(0, 0)[0], rvec.get(1, 0)[0], rvec.get(2, 0)[0]));
            object.setPosition(new Vector3(tvec.get(0, 0)[0], tvec.get(1,  0)[0], tvec.get(2, 0)[0]));

            getCurrentScene().addChild(object);
        } catch (ParsingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the issue isn't inaccuracy. it's that your code is wrong and the results are arbitrary. please add a picture to your post that shows the results. you seem to be using rvec/tvec wrong. use `cv::Rodrigues` to turn the rvec into a rotation matrix. **and**, matrix multiplication is done using `cv::transform` or `cv::gemm`, or using C++ operator `*` on two Mat objects (they call that "matrix expressions"): https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#gacb6e64071dffe36434e1e7ee79e7cb35

Comment: I updated it but it is still inaccurate. 

This how it looks like now : https://imgur.com/a/09jnFu0

and this is the updated code: https://ideone.com/R49In4 

 Is this how it was supposed to be done or is there something missing?

Comment: draw axes on the marker, meaning axes are the object/model. I suspect that your head model's origin is wrong.

Comment: this how it looks like with the axis : https://imgur.com/a/Sll37YA

Comment: that looks correct. the question then is, what is `Object3D` and what kind of data does it want. I understand it's part of the `rajawali` library. I am unfamiliar with that, so that is where my assistance ends.